# Estimating Bias in R

Tags: r

Write a simulation experiment to estimate the bias of the estimator λˆ= 1/ X¯ by sampling
using x=rexp(n,rate=5) and recording the values of 1/mean(x). You should find that the
bias is λ/n−1. Here we’ve used λ = 5 but the result will hold for any λ.
Here is my solution ( I dont get λ/n−1). Am I doing something wrong here?

```
set.seed(1)
lambda <- 5
x <- rexp(n= 1e5, rate = lambda )
samp.mean <- mean(x)
lam.est <- 1/samp.mean
lam.est ##4.986549

bias <- abs(lambda - lam.est)
bias ##0.01345146
```

Comment: This is probably a better question for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r) since it relates to statistical issues. I do not see a problem with your R code.

Answer (score 0):

To start with, there is a mistake in your formula. The bias of the lambda estimator is not lambda/n-1 but **lambda/(n-1)!**

Then note that in order to carry out this experiment correctly, it is not enough to calculate the estimated estimator once.
Do the experiment "n" times on the vector of size "nx".

```
lambda = 3
nx = 150
n = 1e5

set.seed(1)
out = vector("numeric", n)
for(i in 1:n){
  out[i] = 1/mean(rexp(n= nx, rate = lambda))
}
lambda/(nx-1)
mean(out)
bias = abs((mean(out)-lambda))
```

As you can see for `lambda = 3` and `nx = 150` the expression **`lambda/(nx-1)`** is `0.02013423`. And your estimated lambda is `3.019485`.

```
lambda = 5
nx = 200
n = 1e5

set.seed(1)
out = vector("numeric", n)
for(i in 1:n){
  out[i] = 1/mean(rexp(n= nx, rate = lambda))
}
lambda/(nx-1)
mean(out)
bias = abs((mean(out)-lambda))
```

However, for lambda = 5 and nx = 200, the expression `lambda/(nx-1)` is `0.02512563`. And your estimated lambda is `5.024315`.

Perform this experiment for other values of `lambda` and `nx` and you will find that the `bias` of this estimator is **lambda/(n-1)**.